# Python access specific XML node

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this in tree form:

[image: XML tree]

I would like to access the node that contains the branch name and access the value.

So far I've looked into element tree and used this code, but to no avail:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('build_jenkins.xml')

root = tree.getroot()
for node in root.findall('hudson.model.stringparametervalue'):
    name = node.find('name').text
    val = node.get('value')
    print name, value
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: I think you want `root.findall('.//hudson.model.stringparametervalue')`, which looks for nodes with that name at all lower levels, rather than just immediate descendants.

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid

Comment: Please add some XML to your question, and what you want the result to be.